# Database related to users

Tags: mongodb, express, backend, nodes

I am trying to build a full stack application that can remember specific properties when users are logged in. I want to incorporate a database(mongoDB). When the users are logged in, I want the users to be able to add their favourite food items.

As for how I would develop something like this, I am a little bit confused on the back end of things. I just want to make sure my method is appropriate before I start writing code.

As of right now, I am able to add new users to my database, but to remember what a specific users favorite food is, would I just modify the existing database for that specific user?

For example, if I had user A and B and if I add new food to User A, would I just add new food items to the key-value pair associated with user A? Would there be a better way to do this? If it helps, I will also be using node and express. I did read online that I could use cookie session in express, but I want to get familiar with databases.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your method seems like it would work, but it's hard to say without knowing the full use of the "favorite food" feature. If you're just trying to have some text in the user's profile that says "Favorite Food: Pizza and stuff" then your approach is simple and it works. Don't use cookies/sessions if you want to store this information permanently. If you're trying to match users to other people with the same favorite foods or you have a preset list of foods the users must choose from, then you might want to consider other database schema.

I'm not too familiar with MongoDB, but I do know they pride themselves on being ~different~

Check out [this article](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/mongodb-schema-design-best-practices/) from MongoDB, as it seems to explain some different database approaches and MongoDB features and their pros and cons.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. So pretty much what I am trying to implement is the home page has a login. Users are able to login and see a list of their favourite food items. They can add and delete the list of food items. Then they can log out and another user can login and see their list of food items. I don't think it's entirely complex to implement, but I just want to make sure I am on the right track.

Comment: If you're just having a text field they can edit with their favorite food items, your original idea sounds good. Just a "favFood": "pizza" within the user's record works.

Comment: Hello, thanks again for the response. Would you say having a list of their favorite foods would also work too. I'm thinking about storing something like "favFood": ['pizza', 'bbt'] .

Comment: I think as long as you can manage it on the front end, go for it.